# how to extract strings

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

My data is like below

```
sp|Q9H9K5|MER34_HUMAN(9-21)
sp|Q9H9K5|MER34_HUMAN(493-507)
sp|Q9H9K5|MER34_HUMAN(524-539)
sp|P31689|DNJA1_HUMAN(22-33)
sp|P31689|DNJA1_HUMAN(66-82)
sp|P31689|DNJA1_HUMAN(93-104)
sp|P08246|ELNE_HUMAN(7-27)
sp|P08246|ELNE_HUMAN(72-83)
sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN(5-13)
```

I am trying to extract the string between `||`

```
sed -n " ||" file
grep "||" file
```

did not work .

desire output is like this

```
Q9H9K5
Q9H9K5
Q9H9K5
P31689
P31689
P31689
P08246
P08246
P10144
```

Then I want to make them unique

```
 Q9H9K5
 P31689
 P08246
 P10144
```

Comment: It's easy to solve it when you use awk, just two steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
awk -F\| '{print $2}' input_file|sort -u
```

Comment: does not make them unique, just sort them

Comment: @Learner, did you saw the key `-u` at the end of sort? This is to output only unique values (after sort)

Comment: ... or all in awk: `awk -F'|' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}' input_file`

Comment: @Romeo Ninov I liked it already

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut` here to nice effect.

```
cut -d\| -f2 myfile.txt
```

Produces the following output:

```
Q9H9K5
Q9H9K5
Q9H9K5
P31689
P31689
P31689
P08246
P08246
P10144
```

The -d tells `cut` to look out for the pipe character to delimit the columns of your output (in this case we must escape it). The -f specifies which column (or columns) of your input you want back. Columns are numbered starting with 1.

If you only want the unique values, you can pipe that output into sort and uniq as follows:

```
cut -d\| -f2 myfile.txt | sort | uniq
```

This produces:

```
P08246
P10144
P31689
Q9H9K5
```

Comment: Alternatively: `cut -d '|' -f 2 file | sort -u` or with just `uniq` instead of `sort -u` if the data is already sorted.

Comment: You can use `sort -u` instead of `sort|uniq`

Comment: @mttpgn  I liked it already